# I am searching a loop which stores values in a matrix

Tags: matlab, loops, graph

I have an input-table. It has 3 columns and some rows -> The first column are my x-coordinates and the second column are my y-coordinates. (Of my start points)
This start point is always my left bottom corner point of my rectangle. From this point I want to draw my rectangle. (Height and width should be a constant). I have big problems with loops and matrices:

My output must be looking like:

```
AllPoints= [0,0;1,0;1,1;0,1;5,5;10,5;10,10;5,10;2,2;4,2;4,4;2,4];
```

-> Explanation see screenshot

```
  [clc % löscht den Bildschirm
  clear all % löscht alle Variablen

  %Table -> (start Points...)
  %12   0   10
  %14   0   30
  %16   0   54
  %18   0   51
  %20   0   35
  %22   0   12
  %14   2   25
  %16   2   35



  Input_Matrix = readtable('Testbeispiel_Rainflow.dat',...
      'Delimiter','\t','ReadVariableNames',false)%,'Format','%f%f%f')][1]
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to [SO]. You forgot to tag your questions as about Matlab which is why you had not answers. No Matlab specialist could find them! I have fixed this for you. Please read [ask] for more advice on getting answers.

Comment: It's hard to understand what you're asking. You don't need to loop in MATLAB to store variables in a matrix; you can assign directly, possibly using indexing or 'reshape' if you want to transform the data. If you want to display the data as rectangles, look into the 'patch' command to draw arbitrary shapes from (X,Y) pairs.